# siunitx does not detect semi-bold font

Tags: fonts, siunitx

The option `detect-all` of the package `siunitx` should apply all font attributes of the surrounding text to the quantity and the unit. However, this does not seem to work for semi-bold text, see the following example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{MyriadPro}
\renewcommand{\bfdefault}{sb}
\usepackage[detect-all]{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\sffamily\bfseries \SI{230}{V} line voltage}
\end{document}
```

Is this just a bug?
How can I work around it?

Comment: Please provide a link for `MyriadPro.sty` since it is not part of TeX Live and not on CTAN.

Comment: That's right. And most people would not have the Myriad Pro fonts either since they are not free. I'm so much used to them, I did not think about that. Nevertheless I just tried to replicate the problem with the Cabin fonts (included in TeX Live) that also provide a semi-bold weight. But with \usepackage{cabin} I cannot use the semi-bold font at all. \bfseries always selects bold, regardless of the definition of \bfdefault.

Comment: For `cabin`, you just need to read the documentation and set the appropriate package option. And/or use commands from `fontaxes` which `cabin` uses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Today I had the same problem. The cause is that the detection of weights relies on the first letter of the series and only checks for `b`(bold) and `l` (light). Therefore all other weighs are ignored. I posted an [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/josephwright/siunitx/issues/306).

A hacky solution would be to redefine an internal macro of `siunitx`, which is actually “forbidden” in LaTeX3 conventions and not reliable for future changes. Here’s an example using [*Open Sans* (free)](http://www.opensans.com) and `fontspec` to access all weights. The relevant code is between `snip` and `snap` …

[image]

```
% !TeX program = xelatex
\documentclass[parskip=full]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Open Sans}[
   LetterSpace = 2,
   FontFace = {lt}{n}{* Light},
   FontFace = {sb}{n}{* Semibold},
   FontFace = {bf}{n}{* Bold},
   FontFace = {xb}{n}{* Extrabold},
   FontFace = {lt}{it}{* Light Italic},
   FontFace = {sb}{it}{* Semibold Italic},
   FontFace = {bf}{it}{* Bold Italic},
   FontFace = {xb}{it}{* Extrabold Italic},
]
\DeclareRobustCommand\ltseries{\fontseries{lt}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textlt}{\ltseries}
\DeclareRobustCommand\sbseries{\fontseries{sb}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textsb}{\sbseries}
\DeclareRobustCommand\xbseries{\fontseries{xb}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textxb}{\xbseries}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{detect-all}

\ExplSyntaxOn\makeatletter

% --- snip ---
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_if_in:nnTF { noTF }
\cs_set_protected:Npn \__siunitx_detect_font_weight_text: {
  \tl_if_in:noTF { sb bf xb } { \f@series }
    {
      \cs_set:Nn \__siunitx_font_weight: { \boldmath \use:c { \f@series series } }
    }
    {
      \cs_set:Nn \__siunitx_font_weight: { \use:c { \f@series series } }
    }
}
% --- snap ---

\makeatother\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
Upright shapes:

\textlt{Light: \SI{1.234e-5}{\micro\farad}}

Normal: \SI{1.234e-5}{\micro\farad}

\textsb{Semibold: \SI{1.234e-5}{\micro\farad}}

\textbf{Bold: \SI{1.234e-5}{\micro\farad}}

\textxb{Extrabold: \SI{1.234e-5}{\micro\farad}}


\bigskip
Italic shapes:

\itshape
\textlt{Light Italic: \SI{1.234e-5}{\micro\farad}}

Normal Italic: \SI{1.234e-5}{\micro\farad}

\textsb{Semibold Italic: \SI{1.234e-5}{\micro\farad}}

\textbf{Bold Italic: \SI{1.234e-5}{\micro\farad}}

\textxb{Extrabold Italic: \SI{1.234e-5}{\micro\farad}}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are willing/able to use [`fontspec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fontspec) with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX and OpenType fonts, it works out of the box, using `fontspec` features to set the desired bold weight, like so:

```
\setsansfont{Myriad Pro}[BoldFont=Myriad Pro Semibold]
```

The complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setsansfont{Myriad Pro}[BoldFont=Myriad Pro Semibold]
\usepackage[detect-all]{siunitx}

\begin{document}\sffamily
\textbf{\SI{230}{\volt} line voltage}

{\bfseries \SI{230}{\volt} line voltage}

\SI{230}{\volt} line voltage
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same issue when using LaTeX (not XeLaTeX): The current version of [`siunitx`](https://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) (2018-05-27) is incompatible with the current version of [`FiraSans`](https://ctan.org/pkg/fira) (2019-06-06). More precisely, using, for instance, “book” as the regular (medium) fontseries and/or using “semibold” as the default bold fontseries confuses `siunitx` to the extent that numbers that should be regular are set in boldface and vice versa.

Based on Tobi’s code, I was able to solve the issue as follows (the relevant part is between `% ==>` and `% <==`):

```
% !TeX program = pdflatex


\documentclass[10pt, DIV=14]{scrartcl}


\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[scale=0.96]{XCharter}
\usepackage{FiraMono}
\usepackage[book, semibold, scale=0.92, lining, tabular]{FiraSans}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\lseries}{\fontseries{light}\selectfont}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\thseries}{\fontseries{thin}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textth}{\thseries}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\ulseries}{\fontseries{ultralight}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textul}{\ulseries}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\elseries}{\fontseries{extralight}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textel}{\elseries}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\ltseries}{\fontseries{light}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textlt}{\ltseries}
\DeclareRobustCommand\bkseries{\fontseries{book}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textbk}{\bkseries}
\DeclareRobustCommand\rgseries{\fontseries{regular}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textrg}{\rgseries}
\DeclareRobustCommand\meseries{\fontseries{medium}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textme}{\meseries}
\DeclareRobustCommand\sbseries{\fontseries{semibold}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textsb}{\sbseries}
\DeclareRobustCommand\bdseries{\fontseries{bold}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textbd}{\bdseries}
\DeclareRobustCommand\xbseries{\fontseries{extrabold}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textxb}{\xbseries}
\DeclareRobustCommand\hvseries{\fontseries{heavy}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\texthv}{\hvseries}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{detect-all}

% Fix incompatibility of siunitx (v2018-05-17) with FiraSans (v2019-06-06)
% ==>
\ExplSyntaxOn\makeatletter
\newcommand{\thisseries}{\f@series}
\newcommand{\thisshape}{\f@shape}
\cs_set_protected:Npn \__siunitx_detect_font_weight_text: {%
    \let\origmdseries\mdseries@sf%
    \let\origbfseries\bfseries@sf%
    \let\currentseries\f@series%
    \edef\XcurrentseriesX{/\f@series/}
        % Store the current fontseries but enclose it in some kind of delimiter,
        % because otherwise one-letter fontseries may erroneously triger \boldmath
        % (for instance, ``m'' is contained in ``semibold'')
    % Use \boldmath for any weight above semibold:
    \tl_if_in:noTF
        { /sb/ /b/ /bx/ /eb/ /ub/ /bold/ /extrabold/ /ultrabold/ /heavy/ /black/ /demibold/ /semibold/ }
        { \XcurrentseriesX }
        {% if included in the above list: switch to \mathversion{bold}
            \cs_set:Nn \__siunitx_font_weight: {%
                \boldmath%
                \let\bfseries@sf\currentseries%
                % necessary because siunitx in some way accesses
                % \bfseries@sf from the mweights package
                \fontseries{\bfseries@sf}\selectfont%
            }%
            \let\bfseries@sf\origbfseries%  % restore \bfseries@sf
        }
        {% if not: use \mathversion{normal}
            \cs_set:Nn \__siunitx_font_weight: {%
                \unboldmath
                \let\mdseries@sf\currentseries%
                % necessary because siunitx in some way accesses
                % \bfseries@sf from the mweights package
                \fontseries{\mdseries@sf}\selectfont%
            }%
            \let\mdseries@sf\origmdseries%  % restore \mdseries@sf
        }%
}
\makeatother\ExplSyntaxOff
% <==

\newcommand{\testSI}{%
    \begin{tabular}{@{} p{0.15\textwidth} *{3}{p{0.2\textwidth}} @{}}
        \thisseries/\thisshape &
        \SI{1.234e-5}{\micro\farad} &
        $\SI{1.234e-5}{\micro\farad}$ &
        $1.234 \times 10^{-5} \mathrm{\mu F}$
    \end{tabular}%
}


\begin{document}


\section*{Serif font (XCharter)}

\textmd{\testSI -- \texttt{\textbackslash textmd}} \\
\textbf{\testSI -- \texttt{\textbackslash textbf}} \\
\itshape
\textmd{\testSI -- \texttt{\textbackslash textmd}} \\
\textbf{\testSI -- \texttt{\textbackslash textbf}} \\
\upshape
\testSI -- back to default


\sffamily

\section*{Fira Sans upright shapes}

\textmd{\testSI -- \texttt{\textbackslash textmd}} \\
\textbf{\testSI -- \texttt{\textbackslash textbf}}

\smallskip
\noindent
\textth{\testSI} \\
\textul{\testSI} \\
\textel{\testSI} \\
\textlt{\testSI} \\
\textbk{\testSI} \\
\textrg{\testSI} \\
\textme{\testSI} \\
\textsb{\testSI} \\
\textbd{\testSI} \\
\textxb{\testSI} \\
\texthv{\testSI} \\
\testSI -- back to default


\section*{\textit{Fira Sans italic shapes}}

\itshape
\textmd{\testSI -- \texttt{\textbackslash textmd}} \\
\textbf{\testSI -- \texttt{\textbackslash textbf}}

\smallskip
\noindent
\textth{\testSI} \\
\textul{\testSI} \\
\textel{\testSI} \\
\textlt{\testSI} \\
\textbk{\testSI} \\
\textrg{\testSI} \\
\textme{\testSI} \\
\textsb{\testSI} \\
\textbd{\testSI} \\
\textxb{\testSI} \\
\texthv{\testSI} \\
\testSI -- back to default

\rmfamily\upshape
\section*{Serif font again}

\textmd{\testSI -- \texttt{\textbackslash textmd}} \\
\textbf{\testSI -- \texttt{\textbackslash textbf}} \\
\itshape
\textmd{\testSI -- \texttt{\textbackslash textmd}} \\
\textbf{\testSI -- \texttt{\textbackslash textbf}} \\
\upshape
\testSI -- back to default

\smallskip
\noindent
It works! :-)


\end{document}
```

Here’s a screenshot of the output:

[image: FiraSans and siunitx]